Seeing something weird in Timezone in R
I'm seeing something weird in force_tz in R. I am applying the force_tz function over a list/vector of dates. But the application of this function over the elements in the list are not consistent. The first element is assigned tz MMT and the second is assigned tz IST.
> TAB_CYCLE$cycle_start

"1901-01-01 UTC" "1990-01-01 UTC" NA               NA               NA               NA              
> Sys.timezone()

"Asia/Calcutta"
> TAB_CYCLE <- TAB_CYCLE %>% mutate(cycle_start = force_tz(cycle_start, tzone=Sys.timezone()), cycle_end = force_tz(cycle_end, tzone=Sys.timezone()))
> TAB_CYCLE$cycle_start

"1901-01-01 MMT" "1990-01-01 IST" NA               NA               NA               NA      


Here's a much simpler example:


Do you need force_tzs ?

What is "something weird"? Do you mean the timezone change between 1901 and 1990? (not surprising that there might be some difficulties in consistently assigning timezones over a period of 90 years)? This also has nothing to do with force_tz - as.POSIXct(c("1901-01-01", "1990-01-01"), tz="Asia/Calcutta") gives the same result.

You can see the formatting of the offsets of time for Kolkata here - https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/main/asia#L1308 - in the IANA Time Zone Database, which I'm pretty sure R uses.

Apologies if the question is not being clear. I have a dataframe column (TAB_CYCLE$cycle_start), both are in UTC. When I am using the force_tz function, with mutate to this column, I'm seeing one tz changing to MMT and another to IST.

Following thelatemail, if you look https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/main/asia#L1308, it says 'UNTIL', because there was an evolving system of 'time zones' dependent on many factors, but in 1901 Kolkata was considered MMT and by 1991, IST, and this reflects a history of who controlled/coordinated times. If your added further dates and times (for Kolkata) you could replicate this longitudinal history. Which to question, do you need to force?

Oh my! Thanks for the research! @Chris

Actually @thelatemail did the research for us, and I, like you, did the reading.
